# USB drive with debugging tools

Tags: debugging, usb-drive

I'm putting together a USB drive that should contain tools useful for troubleshooting various software problems encountered by users.

What tools would you recommend that I include?

Main environment: Windows and .NET

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend the following : {Some of them have been already mentioned though}

### LOG ANALYSIS:

TextPad

NotePad++

VIM {for opening very large txt files}

### SYSTEM MONITORING:

Process Explorer {allows to check the threads and dlls loaded}

### CODE/ERROR ANALYSIS:

Reflector

DebugView

WinDbg

Autodump+

Answer (score 2):

- [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) for all the different passwords used by your customers.
- Any application-specific scripts you've built up (SQL, batch files, PowerShell etc).
- [Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryziber.com/w/Home)
- [PSTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) from Sysinternals
- If you're .NET you should get [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Answer (score 1):

**SysInternals Suite**, especially AutoRuns, Process Explorer, and Process Monitor

http://www.sysinternals.com

Answer (score 0):

"DebugView is an application that lets you monitor debug output on your local system, or any computer on the network that you can reach via TCP/IP. It is capable of displaying both kernel-mode and Win32 debug output, so you don't need a debugger to catch the debug output your applications or device drivers generate, nor do you need to modify your applications or drivers to use non-standard debug output APIs."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx